# What design pattern provides a static method to produce a class instance

Tags: matlab, design-patterns

I am trying to understand what design pattern I am stumbling towards... please bear with me the language I am using is Matlab and the OO is a bit weak in some areas, and I am relatively inexperienced in implementing design patterns.

I have a ComplexObject in which the constructor was becoming overly complicated. To begin with my constructor allowed 0, 1 or 2 arguments, that is an "empty" ComplexObject, a ComplexObject built from a ModelObject, or a ComplexObject built from ModelObject+ConfigObject. (The ModelObject and ConfigObject are basic file parsers).

I can't overload constructors in Matlab, so I essentially switch'ed on the class type of the input arguments to the constructor, after I while I changed some of this to static methods so that the constructor was just an empty class initializer, and static ComplexObject.createFromModel and ComplexObject.createFromModelAndConfig classes produced ComplexObjects.

I then decided that my ComplexObject code was being dominated by all this construction stuff and the business logic wasnt clear, so I wrote a ComplexObjectFactory class and basically moved the static methods into that class. Now since the static methods are in fact calling more private (static!?) methods to build the ComplexObject I have run into some confusion about calling conventions of these private static methods :(

Finally, I am now trying to add some code to write part of ComplexObject back to disk. Interestingly this is actually the same disk file that is used to build a ConfigObject... so I want something like ComplexObject.writeConfigFile... or should that be ComplexObjectFactory.writeConfigFile(myComplexObject). To further complicate things I want multiple types of "config" file formats down the track.

My current classes look something like:

```
classdef ComplexObjectFactory
    methods (Static)
        function product = createFromModel(modelObj)
            product = ComplexObject()
            ComplexObjectFactory.helper1(product)
        end
        function product = createFromModelAndConfig(modelObj, configObj)
            product = ComplexObjectFactory.createFromModel(modelObj)
            ComplexObjectFactory.helper2(product, configObj)
        end
    end
    methods (Private, Static)
        function helper1(product)
        function helper2(product)
    end
end
classdef ComplexObject
    methods
        function self = ComplexObject(varargin)
            <init>
        end
    end
end

classdef ComplexObject
```

Comment: take a look at these: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creational_pattern

Comment: thanks, I have been going through these.

Comment: I'm wondering if my "factory" is really a builder? I don't really have different ComplexObjects, nor plans to subclass this...

Comment: the intent of the builder pattern is: "Separate the construction of a complex object from its representation so that the same construction process can create different representations." so you may not really have a full design pattern here. this may just be some kind of "factory" helper method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I completely understand your question,  tell me if I'm off topic here.

Just like you wrote, design pattern that creates objects is called factory. Other functionality that you mentioned, like writing to disk should be the responsibility of the object itself.

Comment: thanks, i guess im just worried that writing out to disk will pollute the ComplexObject (aka business logic)

Comment: This is a question of roles and responsibilities of you object. If you feel that some functionality doesn't belong to its business logic, extract it to a dedicated module and define an interface between it and your business logic module.

Comment: well, the business logic of ComplexObject is calculate a value using some properties  which are arrays of (lets say) InterestingObjects. The ConfigObject sets some values (lets say weightings) on the InterestingObjects. I also load some data from a DataObject.... I think it is the responsibility of the ComplexObject to write its state/configuration out to disk... I have refactored the actual I/O away from the ComplexObject, but the method to actually serialize it out is going to be a bit long/ugly :(

Comment: Yes, it sounds like it should indeed be responsible to write the config to disk but that doesn't mean that it has to be inside its own logic. It's very reasonable to delegate the actual writing to another module.

Comment: what I am confused about is, if the delegation to another module requires understanding of the implementation of the ComplexObject, then in doing so do i create a maintenance nightmare if I change ComplexObject? .... in fact this is causing me to lean back towards moving the factory methods back into the ComplexObject class

Comment: That's what design-by-contract is for (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_by_contract). There should be a clear and well-defined interfaces between your modules. Whatever is their internal implementation, it shouldn't change the contract, i.e. the interfaces should stay the same. This requires understanding of your system requirements and needs - this way you will be able produce a design that will absorb future changes locally in the affected modules without breaking the contract.

Comment: I just revisited this quite some time on. I have continued to use a Factory class to create the ComplexObject(s). Going to port this to Java soon and I don't have a good reason to change this approach (yet!)